# Finding the function given its derivative and some conditions.

Tags: integration, solution-verification

> Let $f:[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\to \mathbb R$ be continuous and satisfy $f'(x)=\frac1{1+\cos(x)}$ for all $x\in(0,\frac\pi2)$. If $f(0)=3$ then $f(\frac\pi2)$ has the value equal to:

One would simply do get $f(x)=\tan{\frac x2}+C$ and then $C=3$. So $f(\frac\pi2)=4$. But lets make things a bit more complicated. 
The given integral would equal: $$\int\frac{2}{2+e^{ix}+\frac1{e^{ix}}}dx$$
$$=2\int\frac{e^{ix}}{(e^{ix}+1)^2}dx$$
$$=\frac2i\int\frac{dt}{t^2}$$
(Letting $e^{ix}+1$=t) 
$$=-2i(-\frac1t)+C=\frac{2i}{e^{ix}+1}+C$$
Now we have $f(0)=3$, so $$f(0)=i+C=3$$
So $C=3-i$
$$f(\frac\pi2)=\frac{2i}{e^{i\frac\pi2}}+3-i=5-i$$ 
So where did I commit the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have$$2\int\frac{e^{ix}}{(e^{ix}+1)^2}dx\\=\frac2i\int\frac{dt}{(t+1)^2}\\=\frac{2i}{e^{ix}+1}+C$$When x=0, C=3-i. When $x=\pi/2$, we have
$$\frac{2i}{e^{i\pi/2}+1}+3-i\\=\frac{2i}{cos(\pi/2)+isin(\pi/2)+1}+3-i$$which equals 4

Comment: Ahhh! So there was the mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The real part of $\frac{2i}{e^{ix}+1}$ is $\frac{2\sin(x)}{\sin^2(x)+(\cos(x)+1)^2}$. On this real part, the real part of constant of integration is $C = 3$. Evaluating real part at $\pi/2$, we get $4$.

By writing $f(0) = i + C = 3$, you are assuming that the integrand involving $i$ is real-valued. We have information only about the real part of $C$. So we need to isolate real parts and then apply boundary conditions.